# I can't locate a file downloaded to internal storage from firebase

Tags: android, file, firebase, firebase-storage

The code below works just fine.It downloads a pdf file from firebase storage and saves it in the devices internal storage. What seems to be the trouble here is that I could not find the downloaded file in the Android Device Monitor.

```
btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String magazineUrl= magazineUri[0];

                    new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                                // Creating a reference to the link
                                StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(magazineUrl);

                                File file;
                                file=new File(mContext.getFilesDir(),"DownloadedMagazines.pdf");

                                httpsReference.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                        System.out.println("It has been downloaded");
                                        // Local temp file has been created
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        // Handle any errors
                                        System.out.println("It has failed to download");

                                    }
                                });
                            }catch (final Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();


                }
            });
```

My questions are, Where is the file stored? Is there a possible way to retrieve the path of the downloaded file?

Comment: You are using getFilesDir() path and it returns `/data/data/{your package name}/files`, however this vary at times on platform versions.

Comment: What verison are you using?

Comment: What does logcat show if you log the value of `file`?

Comment: Also bear in mind that the new Thread is completely unnecessary here.  There are no blocking calls in any of the code inside the runnable.  Firebase APIs are all asynchronous.

Comment: @kapsym my firebase version?

Comment: Nope your android version. But since you are using an internal directory path, it would mostly be in /data folder

Comment: @kapsym I'm having a trouble expanding the /data directory, what should I do?

Comment: It wont expand if you are trying to do it for a device. You need a rooted device for that. If you are simulator, it might not expand on Android N and above as there is some issue there. If you want it to be accessible, use externalStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is stored in the private directory of your application.
If you want to save your file in a public directory, use :

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); // For example
File file = new File(path, "DownloadedMagazines.pdf");
```

You can use `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` or `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` and others...

Take care, you need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, and starting in KITKAT, read access requires the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: I thought getExternalStorageDirectory() saves a file on External Storage?

Comment: @NathanDamtew No, from the doc : Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Comment: Okay...But I don't want the other applications to access the file stored, can I still use it?

Comment: No, your file will be in a public directory, so all applications can access it. You can only access to public file from Android Device Monitor unless your device is rooted (or via an emulator) --> Maybe your just need an emulator or rooted device to access your file via ADM ?

Comment: I get it now, Let me try it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I granted both Write and Read Permissions but I keep running to the same errors: Exception occurred during file write.  Aborting.
                                                   java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Comment: E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                   An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                    Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200

Comment: Thanks toooooo much. I kept searching about that for hours. As @NathanDamtew thought I also thought that the word external means writing in the external storage and thus I expected the file to be public and accessible using the file explorer. Your code helped me a lot. Thanks.